# Reformat Plucked Date in Laravel Collective Select

Tags: php, laravel

I am using **[Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/)** forms in my project, and have been commonly using the code below to populate my select dropdowns.

However, I am coming across an issue where I want to convert a database `date` stored in `YYYY-MM-DD` format to be more readable as `MM/DD/YYYY`.

For the rest of my code, I have been using php's `date/strtotime` format like so:

`date('m/d/Y', strtotime($date))`

Does anyone have any ideas for how I can convert what is plucked from my database to display correctly in the laravel collective select dropdown?

**Controller**

```
$scripts_select = Script::orderBy('prescribe_date', 'desc')
    ->pluck('prescribe_date', 'id');
```

**Blade**

```
{{Form::label('script', 'Script')}}
{{Form::select(
    'script',
    $scripts_select,
    $prescription->script_id, 
    ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select a Script']
)}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain the `->map()` method and change the `value` of each item as below:

```
$scripts_select = Script::orderBy('prescribe_date', 'desc')
    ->pluck('prescribe_date', 'id')->map(function ($date, $key) {
        return date('m/d/Y', strtotime($date))
    })->all();
```

Comment: This is a good solution and will work fine. But just something more to consider...If you want to do this in multiple places, you might consider setting an attribute for the Script model which converts the date format for you. Then you would just set the $appends array on the Script model to include that property. Then you could just pull a script and access the custom date format like this: $script->prescribeDateCustomFormat or whatever you want to call it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a change to test this however, you may be able to `->map()` after the `->pluck()` method to change the format.

Try the following:

```
$scripts_select = Script::orderBy('prescribe_date', 'desc')
    ->pluck('prescribe_date', 'id')
    ->map(function ($script, $key) {
        $script['prescribe_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $script['prescribe_data'])->format('m/d/Y');
        return $script;
    });
```

Here, we loop through each `script`, reformatting all `presribe_date` using `Carbon`.